# I am able to run the script with 2 users but not with the multiple users in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am able to run the script with 2 users but not with the multiple users in jmeter.

My observations after recording the script for few requests :
Under Workbench - View results tree - Response as

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:118)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:210)
```

Sampler result response:  Response message:`Connection reset
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate``**

And i have  added JmeterROOTCA certificate in Browser.

Could anyone please suggest why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

1. The error you're getting is connected with **recording** tests, not executing the tests. Normally you don't need to add certificates especially into browser for the tests execution. If you're not able to record the test follow instructions from the "HTTPS recording and certificates" chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry. Sometimes [clearing your browser history](https://www.howtogeek.com/304218/how-to-clear-your-history-in-any-browser/) helps
2. Workbench was removed in [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4/) so it looks like you're using quite and outdated JMeter version and according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest one